# Rails render is inserting a blank space

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm pretty new to rails and I'm getting a weird issue when I try to render a partial. Instead of just rendering the HTML, it's adding a blank space surrounded by quotes above the partial's content.

**> View (index.html.erb)**

```
<div>
  <%= render 'shared/rightColumn' %>
</div>
```

**> Partial (_rightColumn.html.erb)**

```
<div>
    Some Content...
</div>
```

**> Result...**

```
<div>
  ""
  <div>
    Some Content...
  </div>
</div>
```

This causes the content of my partial to be shifted down in the view because the browser is accounting for that blank space. If I add one comment before the call to render and another at the start of the partial's content, the blank space is added between the two comments.

I'd rather not add negative margins to try and hack my way around this. And Rails is used heavily enough that I'm sure this is my fault. I just can't figure a way around it. Should I not be using render? Or am I misusing it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your CSS is reset.

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not an issue with css. There's actually a set of quotes being inserted into the DOM and the browser is accounting for that by adding white space.